# How to update model with ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am developing my first Ruby on Rails real application, and I want to achieve a very simple task:

I have an input in my view, whose value represents a field of one of my models. I want to, via ajax, update this field in my model when the user changes the value of the input.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot

html code:

```
Product#View
...
Stock: <input type="text" name="p[stock]" placeholder="Stock" value="<%= @product.stock %>" /><br>
...
```

controller:

```
def view
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: It'll be easier for us to help if you post some code. Can you post the form and the controller it's posting to?

Comment: @LannyBose I posted the code I have, it just renders the input with it's value. I have no clue how to ajax-update it.

Comment: This article is pretty thorough, and I think covers your use case: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails